# verifyIdToken works one time and fails another time

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail-api, google-signin

I'm trying to implement google sign-in to on my website.
I've done the steps from here [Authenticate with Google.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)
This function executes after i have logged in to google :

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var googleResponse = googleUser.getAuthResponse();
    google_login(googleResponse, true);
};
```

Google_login function:

```
function google_login(res) {
    var httpObject = getXMLHTTPObject();

    var ajax_url =  siteURL + 'google_login';
    var params = 'token='+encodeURIComponent(res.id_token);

    httpObject.open('POST', ajax_url, true);
    httpObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    httpObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpObject.readyState == 4) {
            if(httpObject.responseText == 'true') {
                window.location = httpObject.responseURL;
            }
            else {
                if(httpObject.responseText == '') {
                    window.location = siteURL + 'login_again';
                }
                else {
                    window.location = siteURL + 'google_login_error';
                }
            }
        }
    };

    httpObject.send(params);
}
```

And in my model I'm using this code:

```
private $google_client;
function Google_model() { 
    parent::__construct();
    $this->google_client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => 'my_client_id','client_secret' =>'my_client_secret']);
}

function check_google_user($access_token) {
    $payload = $this->google_client->verifyIdToken($access_token);
    if ($payload) {
        return $payload;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In my controller I'm calling *check_google_user* function.
And here appears a strange behaviour. Sometimes when I try to login I get the payload, and sometimes not (PS: I'm trying to login with the same user in the same day). Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

I'm getting this error: *Caught exception: Cannot handle token prior to 2017-01-25T16:20:24+0200*

Comment: [go through this](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/pull/828) you can find problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved this by commenting these lines in firebase JWT.php file:

```
throw new BeforeValidException(
            'Cannot handle token prior to ' . date(DateTime::ISO8601, $payload->iat)
);
```

Comment: This literally breaks the whole purpose of JWT and you should NEVER do this